# How to Export .JAR File Without All Included Libraries (Especially SWT lib)

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, swt

I'm working on a small SWT java program. When I export it to runnable .jar file, all libraries are included, of course. But the size of the .jar file is big (~2.5 MB) compared to the code (~37KB). The biggest library is the SWT lib, which is ~2.4 MB.
Can I export .jar file without the SWT lib or other libraries? if not, what is the best solution to have smaller .jar file size?